# Deny direct access of a pdf file but allow when user logged in

Tags: php, .htaccess, file

I have a little issue with my php app, i have a folder named "my_files" inside this i have many pdf inside many directories.
Inside "my_files" directory i put this htaccess line to deny direct access form url (working fine) :

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

On my root project i put this php file (get_file.php) to allow pdf download only for logged-in members :

```
if( !empty( $_GET['pdf_name'] ) ) {
  // check if user is logged    
 if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    $pdf_name = preg_replace( '#[^-\w]#', '', $_GET['pdf_name'] );
    $pdf_folder = {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/docs/en;
    $fic = "{$pdf_folder}/{$pdf_name}.pdf";
    if( file_exists( $fic ) ){
        header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );*/
        header( 'Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fic}" );
        header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
        readfile( $fic );
        exit;
    }
  }
} else {
    die( "ERROR: you don't have permissions to download it." );
}
```

And when i access this url :

```
myappdomaindotcom/get_file.php?pdf_name=STUDENTS
```

the browser returns :

```
This web page is not available
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

Could someone help me please? the aim is to disallow file direct access but allow only for logged in members.

## UPDATE

On browser console i got this response : 
Why i have data:image ????

[image: browser console]

## UPDATE V2

I changed a bit the code to add quote but i got same result, the file really exists but the console returns the same failed status.

```
if( !empty( $_GET['pdf_name'] ) ) {
  // check if user is logged    
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {


    $pdf_name = preg_replace( '#[^-\w]#', '', $_GET['pdf_name'] );
    $pdf_folder = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/docs/en";
    $pdf_file   = "{$pdf_folder}/{$pdf_name}.pdf";
    echo $pdf_file;
    if( file_exists( $pdf_file ) )
    {

        header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
        header( 'Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$pdf_file}" );
        header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
        readfile( $pdf_file ); 

    }
  }
} else {
    die( "ERROR: you don't have permissions to download it." );
}
```

## UPDATE V3 WORKING

I finally solved it from this post : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259319/htaccess-disallow-direct-access-to-all-files-except-logged-in-users-php), below is final code :

```
if( !empty( $_GET['pdf_name'] ) ) {

 // check if user is logged    
 if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $proxiedDirectory   = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/xxxx/";
    $filename           = $_GET['pdf_name'];
    $file               = $proxiedDirectory.$filename.'.pdf';
    $basename           = basename($file);

    if( file_exists($file) ){
        $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

        header("Content-Type: application/pdf", true, 200); //May need to determine mime type somehow
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$basename}");
        header('Cache-Control: public');
        readfile($file);
        exit();
    }

}

} else { die( "ERROR: you don't have permissions to download it." );}
```

Thank you for you helps guys, but i have a last question : is it possible to open pdf instead of downloading it?

Comment: Well, you should check what the actual response is your browser receives. Open your browsers development console, select the "Networking" tab and examine the request.

Comment: Hello thank you, i updated my question, i get failed response.

Comment: Instead of deny all, try adding to allow the server ip. Or put the files outside the webroot and use absolute path to access them

Comment: @RST Sorry, but that makes absolutely no sense. THe rules in that dynamic configuration file, so the `Deny from all` is only relevant for http requests. The code the OP posted does not do that. It uses `readfile()` which will do a file system file access.

Comment: @Martin You want to rethink your proposed code. It does not really make sense, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha sorry I got interrupted just as I posted it, I mean that the variable reference should be encased in double quotes. Else it's a PHP syntax error. `$pdf_folder = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/docs/en";`

Comment: @user44321 you should take your **V3 Working Update** and set it as an answer and then mark it as the answer so in future people can see how to solve this problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

error line this   $pdf_folder = {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/docs/en; not string .

```
if( !empty( $_GET['pdf_name'] ) ) {
  // check if user is logged    
 if( is_user_logged_in() ){
    $pdf_name = preg_replace( '#[^-\w]#', '', $_GET['pdf_name'] );
    $pdf_folder = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/docs/en";
    $fic = "{$pdf_folder}/{$pdf_name}.pdf";
    if( file_exists( $fic ) ){
        header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
        header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );*/
        header( 'Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fic}" );
        header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
        readfile( $fic );
        exit;
    }
  }
} else {
    die( "ERROR: you don't have permissions to download it." );
}
```

Comment: It might help to explain what you changed and why

Comment: @RST php string always single quotes or double is true .

Comment: I know. Your answer is just not complete without an explanation.

Comment: You get this error - >Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'  this syntax is  $pdf_folder = {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/docs/en;

Comment: I thing one more you this line  $pdf_name = preg_replace( '#[^-\w]#', '', $_GET['pdf_name'] );   replace  and test like this  $pdf_name =  $_GET['pdf_name']; i hope work it .try this.

Comment: Hello, thank you, i did as you say but it returns me 404 error now, even i remove all header and readfile inside if(file_exists(...))